# update multi level plist objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array, plist

I'm able to read data from a multi level plist without any problems.

I'm also able to edit a single dimensional plist using the following:

```
NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *destinationPath= [doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

// Read from document directory
NSMutableDictionary *settingsItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:destinationPath];

// update the dictionary
[settingsItem setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"score"];

// write back to file
[settingsItem writeToFile:destinationPath atomically:YES];
```

But I can't update a multi level plist.

how would I edit score on a plist that looks like this?

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>level1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>level</key>
        <string>level1.tmx</string>
        <key>music</key>
        <string>level1.mp3</string>
        <key>score</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>level2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>level</key>
        <string>level2.tmx</string>
        <key>music</key>
        <string>level2.mp3</string>
        <key>score</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSPropertyListSerialization` with the option `NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves` so that all levels of the returned object graph are mutable. Then you can edit the objects and write them back out.